# Find a monic polynomial with a cos root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Find a monic, irreducible polynomial with a root at $\cos (π/5)$

Comment: $x-\cos{(\pi/5)}$

Comment: The number $\cos(\pi/5)$ is not an algebraic integer, so such a monic polynomial does not exist with integer coefficients.  Either rational coefficients must be allowed or $\cos(\pi/5)$ has to be multiplied by $2$ (that product _is_ an algebraic integer).  Please clarify which direction to take.

Comment: You might want to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136978/showing-that-cos-left-frac-pi5-right-frac12-phi.

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113466/show-4-cos2-frac-pi5-2-cos-frac-pi5-1-0

Answer (score 3):

The question is not precise but I think you want to find  polynomial with integer coefficient. Assuming that:

$\frac{\pi}{5}$ is a solution of trig equation $\cos(5x)=-1$. Now you expand $\cos{5x}$ in terms of powers of $\cos x$. You can use Euler’s formula and show this :
$$\cos{5x}=16\cos^5{x}-20\cos^3x+5\cos x $$
After that put $x=\frac{\pi}{5}$ and $t=\cos x$.
Finally note that $16t^5-20t^3+5t+1=(t+1)(4t^2-2t-1)^2$ and take it from here

Answer (score 1):

If $5x=(2n+1)\pi,5\nmid(2n+1)\implies\cos x\ne-1$

$$\cos(3x)=-\cos2x$$

Expand both sides to form a cubic equation is n $\cos x$

Divide both sides by $\cos x+1$ as $\cos x\ne-1$